# Convert.FromBase64String Returns length and invalid padding characters errors

Tags: c#, encoding, web

I am currently running around in circles for the "Convert.FromBase64String" function. It first threw the error for string not being for a correct length, So I fixed the error using following code...

```
         private static byte[] DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding decoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = null;
        int mod4 = encodedData.Length % 4;
        try
        {
            if (mod4 > 0)
            {
                encodedData = encodedData.Trim('\0');
                encodedData += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
            }
            encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
            returnValue = decoder.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return encodedDataAsBytes;
    }
```

Now it throws error "The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.". Obviously its adding another padding character at the end to make the string correct length (multiplication of 4).

Not sure how to solve this?

Any idea ?

Comment: _"Not sure how to solve this?"_ - by passing it a valid Base64 string. Your original input would perhaps solve the issue.

Comment: You haven't shown us your full code, but I can immediately see that if `mod4` is `1`, you will append *three* padding characters, which is never valid (as the error message says). Which of the three error conditions mentioned in the error message is the actual problem for the string you are passing?

Comment: Thanks AakashM, I have updated the full code.

Comment: What's the original value of `encodedData` in the particular case that gives you an error?

Comment: I will not be able to put the actual text but length of the actual text is 23 with two "=" at the end. Now to make it multiplication of 4 it needs to either remove three characters (which would make the decryption failed as loss of valid characters) or to add another "=" which throws "The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters."

Comment: " length of the actual text is 23 with two "=" at the end" - this means something is going wrong earlier in the process. You can't take an arbitrary string and magically make it a correct base64 string. If you have a length 23 string, it is *not* a base64 encoded string - you need to work out what's gone wrong before this point.